# How to use $_GET method values into a separate PHP document

Tags: php, get

Say I have an **`index.php`** page with a form with the action to another PHP document that submits the form data into a database.

In this PHP document, I am uploading some user information to a database, but I also want to upload a subject that is in the browser's URL. my URL is ***index.php?subject=test***

I understand that I can use **`$_GET['subect']`** to grab the information in the URL, but I can only use this in my main **`index.php`** page.

When I try to use this get method in my linked PHP page, It doesn't recognize it. **What are some ways I can get this method to work**? *Or* what a**re some other ways I can upload the subject located in the url to my database**?

Comment: In your form, put a hidden input that has the name subject and the value test.  It will therefore be passed in the POST, like the other inputs from the form.

Comment: You can save the GET value as a session variable instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

session and cookies keep the message in memory so you can move the content you want between pages

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['value'] = 'Hello World ';
```